# Accessing data in a set

Tags: java, hashset

I have created this new set and want to add items to the set. But it won't get into the loop. I tried running the program and it would not display in the for loop. I am not sure hwy or how I would change the code for it to work.

```
Set<Name> names = Sets.newHashSet();

      for (Name n : names) {
         System.out.println("in the for loop");
         n.setName("Tom);
}
```

Comment: Your `Set` doesn't have anything in it. Why would your code ever enter the loop?

Comment: then how would I access the set name that is within that set?

Comment: What do you think `for (Name n : names)` does?

Comment: @user2811419 You haven't added any names to the Set yet...

Comment: Name n :names loops over every name in names and references it with n, how would I add names to the set then

Comment: The downside of a `Set` is that you can only access to its elements by iterating them. If you want/need to access to a specific element, it would be better using a `List<Name>` or a `Map<SomeKey, Name>`.

Comment: `Set` has an `add(Object)` Method. `Set<Name>` has a `add(Name)` method.

Comment: You have to add a `Name` before you can reference it.

Comment: So if I create an arrayList and set all the names in the list then use the names.add(arrayList) that would work?

Comment: You need to create a `Name` object and `add()` it to the collection before you can iterate the collection, retrieve a reference to it, and call `setName()` on it. You haven't even created any `Name` objects anywhere yet.

Comment: This code does not compile: `n.setName("Tom);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what your program does, in English:

```
 Set<Name> names = Sets.newHashSet();
```

Let's create a new empty set of names, that we'll call "names"

```
for (Name n : names) {
```

Let's iterate through all the names present in the empty set we have just created. This obviously is useless, since the set is empty.

```
    System.out.println("in the for loop");
```

Let's write to the console that we're in the loop. This will never be executed, since the set is empty.

```
    n.setName("Tom);
```

Let's change the name of the current Name object in the loop. But since the loop is never executed, it will never happen.

Before iterating over elements in a set, add elements to the set:

```
Name n = new Name("Tom"); // this creates an new object of type Name
names.add(n); // this adds the Name we just created to the set. 
              // Now the set has 1 element.
```

If you want to add several names to the set, you can also use a loop, and create and ad a new Name at each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Name n = new Name("Tom " + i);
    names.add(n);
}
// now the set contains 10 elements: Tom 0, Tom 1, ..., Tom 9
```